# Rails 4: How to upload an image on mobile?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I try to select an image, I get redirected to original page(page reloads), all the data(name, email...) is lost and image is not selected. Sometimes it actually works(like 1 out of 10 times I try).

Now, I've tried selecting an image, then uploading it on many other popular sites and it works fine. Is there a problem in my rails app, since it works fine on other sites?

Here's a simple form I'm using. It's a registration form using the devise gem:

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
...
<%= f.file_field :image %>
```

Comment: Provide more details on what you're testing it with. I've had no problems with it on Chrome for Android. Are you using something different?

Comment: No, I'm using android & chrome as well. I just found this: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53088

Comment: Then there's nothing wrong with Rails, it's Chrome to blame for that. I've been testing a while ago, things have changed apparently.